# Can Qt be used for developing apps for windows IoT core?

Tags: qt, windows-10, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I have been working a while with Qt and C++ environment and want to
learn Windows IoT core and its capabilities. Is there a way to do
that?

Comment: AFAIK, Qt supports ARM architecture, which is underlying architecture of Raspberry Pi. In the other side, Win10-IoT uses Raspberry Pi, so we can then conclude that Qt supports Win10-loT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QT does seem to support a compatible application model to run of Windows 10 IoT Core.

http://doc.qt.io/QtSupportedPlatforms/index.html

Windows 10 IoT Core currently supports:

- Universal App Platform (headed & deadless apps)
- Node.js (headless)
- Python (heal)

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/10/hello-windows-10-iot-core/

Comment: Feel free to check the answer if you think it's ok ;)